# Integrate cos(z) over a quarter of an ellipse.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

The complex form of the equation for an ellipse with foci at 1 and -1 is $|z-1|+|z+1|=\sqrt{8}$.

a) Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ describe the same ellipse.

b) Let $C$ be the quarter of the ellipse starting at the right most point and ending at the top most point (one quarter of the ellipse).  Calculate $\int_C \cos z\ dz$.

For part a) I was able to obtain the values $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1$.  For part b) I paramterized the ellipse as $z(t)=\sqrt{2}\cos t+i\sin(t)$, and therefore $\dot{z}(t)=-\sqrt{2}\sin t+i\cos t$, and the integral (I think) should be

$\int_C \cos z\ dz=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(z(t))\dot{z}(t)\ dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\sqrt{2}\cos t+i\sin t)\cdot(-\sqrt{2}\sin t+i\cot t)\ dt.$

But I can't evaluate that integral for the life of me.  Another trick I tried was the "Fundamental Theorem" and I got

$\int_C\cos z\ dz=\sin(i)-\sin(\sqrt{2})$,

which I also cannot evaluate.  Can somebody help me find my mistake or lead me toward the solution?  Thanks.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem i.e. Leiniz-Newton is the way to go here.

Comment: Well, I tried that, but I got the result you see above and it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Why not? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sin%5BI%5D

Comment: Well, you know, always expecting a nice clean answer and all that.

Comment: Do you know the exponential form ($z=r\cdot e^{i\varphi}$)?

Comment: @Berci Yes I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment says, the Newton-Leibniz theorem is the way.

The power series $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\dots$ converge not only for all real $z$, but also for all complex $z$. This defines the exponential function $e^z$. It turns out that if $z$ is purely imaginary, then $e^z$ is moving on the unit circle of the complex plane, moreover
$$e^{i\varphi}=\cos\varphi+i\,\sin\varphi\,.$$
From it one can get the power series of $\cos$ and $\sin$ simultaneously, or we can express from above that
$$\cos\varphi=\frac{e^{i\varphi}+e^{-i\varphi}}2,\quad\quad \sin\varphi=\frac{e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi}}{2i}\,.$$
But, the same way as above, these expressions also make sense when $\varphi\in\Bbb C$. 
 Namely, we get $\cos(i\,x)=\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(i\,x)=i\sinh(x)$.